# Weekday or month! Which one should I group my data by?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have a data set listing activities over a year (in logistics context). I can see that the loads are much more different across day of the week (e.g. Wednesdays are super busy while Sundays are very empty), but a teammate argue that grouping by month is a better idea (e.g. Jan vs Dec).

I wonder if there is any appropriate statistical analysis to prove which grouping is more appropriate?

Thanks,

Comment: You could technically incorporate both levels of seasonality in a forecasting model. If you want to do groupings and see he seasonal efects, then do the grouping, and then make autocorrelation analysis: shift your timeseries of grouped counts by 7 for weekly pattern, and by 12 for monthly pattern. Check hypothesis that correlation is zero, observe the test statistic, and comape those statstics. I can give you an example if tis way looks good.

Comment: The two seasonalities may interact, i.e., the weekday pattern may be stronger in summer than in winter. Our [tag:multiple-seasonalities] tag may be useful. In any case, the main question is why you want to group your data at all. What do you want to do with your grouped data afterwards? For instance, if you want to forecast for monthly production planning, then the weekday patterns are indeed less relevant. So please clarify what your larger question is.

Comment: Thank you @StephanKolassa. There is no certain reason to why I need to group the data, it is a dataset from work and I try to do some dice and slice to bring more understanding about the operations in the field!

In one of our meetings, there was a discussion as someone said the data should be grouped monthly (maybe because he's used to it) but people who are more involved in the operational aspect stated that the day of the week is a stronger aspect, thus the analysis and report should be based on day of the week!
I am trying to find an academic approach to accept / reject each of those.

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is essential exploratory, then there is no "more appropriate" grouping, so no statistical way of deciding. It depends on what you want to do. Here, the approach that gives you the most insight will likely be the most useful.

I'd recommend you look at graphical displays. Specifically, you could look at [seasonal plots](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-plots.html) and [seasonal subseries plots](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-subseries-plots.html). These can help you identify whether the variation within weeks or between months is most striking.

Which one is most important may well depend on your audience. Someone involved in B2C distribution may be more concerned with weekday patterns with a short horizon, whereas someone who works in production planning may be less interested in short-term fluctuations and more in longer-term movements, like yearly seasonality.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen K , Appreciate your comprehensive answer and also pointing and considering the industry of the data origin. The reason I am after some proof or statistical analysis to find somehow a "more appropriate" timing is to understand whether I should do more analysis on monthly data (as an example) or running weekly analysis is enough. I am talking about several set of analysis for multiple terminals, which aside from the time consuming and effort on running and adjusting all those analysis, much more effort would be required trying to get some sort of insight from the analysis.